# how to restore focus on existing chrome extension windows, instead of creating a new one?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Im developing a chrome extension which open in a new windows using this code in background.js.

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.windows.create({
        // Just use the full URL if you need to open an external page
        url: chrome.runtime.getURL("popup.html"),
        type: "popup",
        width: 250,
        height: 250,
    });
});
```

i want when user click on extension icon, and already there is an open extension windows, instead of creating a new window, restore the old one
and im using manifest 3

Comment: Use chrome.tabs.query({url: chrome.runtime.getURL("popup.html")})

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you. i inspected my  extension window object and looks like it doesn't have a url. but i managed to retrieve the tab using your hint for now.  but how can i turn the focus on it?

Comment: chrome.windows.update(tab.windowId, {focused: true}); where tab is tabs[0] from tabs.query

Answer (score -1):

You can

a) Define a `default_popup` in `manifest.jsons`'s `action` field:

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/user_interface/#popup

b) Use chrome.storage.local to save the Window id returned by chrome.windows.create().